# R : naiveBayes problems?

Tags: r

My code as follows:

model is very well ,however when I try to predict  yhat ,there is something wrong.

```
spec <- read.table("F:/SPEC.data",sep=",")# 23 columns


model<-naiveBayes(spec[,1:22], spec[,23]) 
yhat = predict(model, spec[,-23])
```

I don't know why yhat is :
factor(0)

Any ideas?

It is works very very on iris just like

```
data(iris) 
model<-naiveBayes(iris[,1:4], iris[,5]) 
yhat = predict(model, iris[,-5])
```

My data just like this:

```
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1
1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1
0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1
1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1
1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, eg. maybe supply a subset of `spec`. Maybe you just need to change it to numeric: `as.numeric(spec[,1:22]), but it's all guessing.`

Comment: (i think) the issue is that your data is being treated as numeric, whereas it is probably a dichotomous factor. So, assuming `spec` is a `data frame` convert all variables to factors with `spec[] <- lapply(spec, factor)`. Then rerun your commands - note that the values in the CPT's in model output look more sensible (marginals summing to one).

Comment: If you *really want* to treat the class variable as numeric (and i think normality is assumed) the raw probabilities seem to be able to be calculated.You can then calculate the max posterior. `yhat <-  (0:1)[max.col(predict(model, spec[,1:22], type="raw"))]`. BUT i think the previous comment is the way to go.